# Python how to upload file to webservice using Flask module?

Tags: python, web-services, post, file-upload, flask

[I'm following this tutorial on how to set up file uploading webservice using Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/fileuploads/). Below is a snipped of my code. I can see that the `def upload_file():` gets the correct filename and allows it through, however, **the line that actually saves the file does not get executed** and I receive "Internal server error (500)" response. It seems that the issue is with actually storing files on disk.

**What else do I need to do to set up my web service to save received files using Flask?**

**UPDATED - the code below works now**

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import Response, jsonify, request, redirect, url_for

#persistent storage in dictionary
import shelve

#printing ip of host
import socket

#file uploading
import os
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename

#serving files that were uploaded
from flask import send_from_directory

#mac-specific relative path to the script's location
UPLOAD_FOLDER = './audio'
ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS = set(['txt', 'm4a', 'mp4'])


#configuration
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER


def allowed_file(filename):
    return '.' in filename and \
        filename.rsplit('.', 1)[1] in ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_file():
    print 'upload file'
    try:
        os.stat(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'])
    except:
        os.mkdir(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'])
    if request.method == 'POST':
        file = request.files['file']
        print 'filename: ' + file.filename

        if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
            print 'allowing file'
            filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
            file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
            return redirect(url_for('uploaded_file',filename=filename))
    return '''
        <!doctype html>
        <title>Upload new File</title>
        <h1>Upload new File</h1>
        <form action="" method=post enctype=multipart/form-data>
        <p><input type=file name=file>
        <input type=submit value=Upload>
        </form>
        '''

@app.route('/uploads/<filename>')
def uploaded_file(filename):
    return send_from_directory(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'],
                               filename)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    print(socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname()))
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

Comment: Does the user that the webserver is running as have permission to write to the `UPLOAD_FOLDER`?

Comment: I'm running the script on a local machine using "python webservice.py". The /audio folder does not exist. Do I need to create it or run the script with elevated permissions (sudo?)

Comment: I tried both creating the "audio" folder and running "sudo python webservice.py", get the same results - no file is being saved. The user has write permission for that folder

Comment: Figured it out - on Mac I have to use ./audio for audio uploads path